# Cmake cannot find package for dji onboard sdk file

Tags: ros, find-package, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I was using dji onboard SDK for develop and meet problems about include sdk file into my project.

I put several project in one workspace,
[image: image description]

After i 'catkin_make' it, it shows error,

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "dji_sdk" with any
  of the following names:

    dji_sdkConfig.cmake
    dji_sdk-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "dji_sdk" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "dji_sdk_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "dji_sdk" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  meteorOnboard/fcu/CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)


-- Could not find the required component 'dji_sdk'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "dji_sdk" with any
  of the following names:

    dji_sdkConfig.cmake
    dji_sdk-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "dji_sdk" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "dji_sdk_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "dji_sdk" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  meteorOnboard/fcu/CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)
```

Any advice appreciated.

Glen

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244843/cmake-cannot-find-package-for-dji-onboard-sdk-file/) by [Glen](https://answers.ros.org/users/19650/glen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2016-10-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Corusco](https://answers.ros.org/users/29124/corusco/) on 2017-01-20**:
Hi, Glen. I'm having some similar trouble. Did you find any solution to your problem? I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I had the same problem, and I could fix it.

I had this:

```
*Call Stack (most recent call first):
 foobar/CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)*
```

So I deleted the folder foobar, I guess that the problem was for something that it was active or who knows... (I'm a beginner)
When I deleted it ( **user@name:~$** rm -R catkin_ws/src/foobar ), then it worked.

In your case says:

```
*Call Stack (most recent call first):
 meteorOnboard/fcu/CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)*
```

So the problem is in the CMakeLists.txt of the folder fcu.

Also:

```
*Could not find a package configuration file provided by "dji_sdk" with any...*
```

Make sure that you install the dji_sdk . Clone it: **user@name:~$** git clone https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK.git

I dont' know if it would help you, actually I'm not really sure how I fix mine  ^^'

---

Originally posted by [paulacb](https://answers.ros.org/users/32454/paulacb/) with karma: 16 on 2017-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0